# Removing a parentless HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to remove the temporary element which is created dynamically.

```
x = document.createElement("DIV");
x.innerHTML = res;
y = x.parentNode;
x = y.removeChild(x);
x = null;
```

I've written those codes but since it does note have a parent, they dont work. I know i can create a second temp node to keep first one but then i need a third node to delete the second one.... :) Here i need a function to delete the node without needing a parent node. I also think that i can put the node to directly to document object and delete it, but i'm looking for more efficient solutions if exists.

Comment: Why do you think you have to delete the node at all?

Comment: If you never add the element to the DOM, then you don't need to remove it from the DOM AFAIK.

Comment: BTW, this question is almost the same as your previous one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194924/does-removechild-really-delete-the-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need not remove the node, since it is not added to the DOM. When you set the variable to `null`, the element will cease to exist. In general, DOM nodes will always have a parent, provided they're added to the model, but here you don't do that in your code.

Answer (score 1):

`removeChild` is just from removing an element from a document. Since your element isn't part of a document, you don't need to use it. Just make sure that you don't have kept any references to the element in your code, for example by setting the variable(s) to `null` just as you are doing, and JavaScript automatic garbage collection will take care of the rest.

If your variable is a local variable in a function, then you don't even need to set it to `null`, because it will cease to exist on it's own.

There is no direct way to "delete" an object in JavaScript.

Comment: Objects **can** be deleted, with certain limitations - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator

Comment: Hmm. The `delete` operator removes the property of an object, not the object itself. For the purpose here, it doesn't do more that setting to `null` (or `undefined`).