# Chrome - Performance Monitor - DOM Nodes keep on stacking

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, dom, nodes

I'm trying to get my head around - why is the DOM Nodes keeps on going up when I'm checking my website in the Performance Monitor.

I've added this simple code that just looping on:

1) adding and element to a wrap, 
2) bind it with a click event. 
3) removing it.

but still the DOM Nodes are always up the I check the performance. 
any thoughts?

[image: image showing the issue and the monitor]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    

    <title></title>
    <style>
        .wrap{
            font-size:50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="wrap">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    

   <script>
       var counter = 0;

       setInterval(function () {

           //increase counter (for display) 
           counter++;

           //get wrap 
           var wrap = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap")[0];

           //remove its children
           while (wrap.firstChild) {
               wrap.firstChild.removeEventListener("click", onclick);

               wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);
           }

           //create new element 
           var div = document.createElement("div");        // create a div element
           div.innerHTML = 'hello mosh (' + counter + ')';
           
           //bind events
           div.addEventListener("click", onclick);

           // append the div to wrap
           wrap.appendChild(div);                                



       }, 200);

       //on click function
       var onclick = function () { alert('click'); }

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194924/does-removechild-really-delete-the-element

Comment: Thank you for comment @epascarello, but I'm doing exactly as it is in their answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The v8 engine is garbage-collected, removed DOM elements are not destroyed immediately.
Occasionally unused (unreachable) objects are garbage-collected.

If I wait long enough, with your code, I do see DOM Nodes go back down to the original value (had to bump the interval to 20 to speed up the process).

[image: v8 gc]

For this reason it is often more efficient to not remove DOM elements, and instead just replace the HTML content.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    

    <title></title>
    <style>
        .wrap2 {
            font-size:50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body >
    <div class="wrap2">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    

   <script>
       var counter = 0;
       var wrap = document.getElementsByClassName("wrap2")[0];
       var div = wrap.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

       setInterval(function () {

           counter++;

           div.innerText = 'hello mosh (' + counter + ')';
           
       }, 20);

       //on click function
       var onclick = function () { alert('click'); }

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: v8 gc]

Comment: This was very informative. Managed to get an insane decrease in the amount of DOM nodes being created every second (from 700 to 16!) within a matter of minutes thanks to this simple advice. Thank you.